# How to replace error with a value in python

Tags: python

I am using AutoSklearn library
in this library, there is a function called leaderboard()

sometimes this function gives error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/my/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/autosklearn/estimators.py", line 841, in leaderboard
    model_runs[model_id]['ensemble_weight'] = weight
KeyError: 1
```

I am using this function as part of a string

```
out = out + "automl.leaderboard() : " + automl.leaderboard() + "\n\r"
```

I want to replace the error with a string value "Error"

how can I do that?

P.S.
Here is the bug description for the error from the library github.

https://github.com/automl/auto-sklearn/issues/1441

Comment: If you're getting an error, that means something is wrong. Why not try to find the root cause of the issue?

Comment: what do you mean "replace"? Do you want to write the error in the `out` variable?

Comment: @ddejohn it is an error because a bug in the library

Comment: @Valentino yes, i want to write "error" in the out variable

Comment: A `KeyError` that occurs "randomly" in a popular library? I find that hard to believe. A "bug in the library" is a bold claim. Where's your evidence that this is in fact a problem with the library itself? Has it been officially acknowledged by the developers? Is there an open issue in their Github?

Comment: @ddejohn Here is the official github bug description and the response from the library makers.
https://github.com/automl/auto-sklearn/issues/1441#issuecomment-1101320899

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `try / except` block. Something like this:

```
try:
    out = out + "automl.leaderboard() : " + automl.leaderboard() + "\n\r"
except KeyError as err:
    out = out + "automl.leaderboard() : " + str(err) + "\n\r"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `try/except` to try to get the leaderboard value, substituting `"Error"` when `KeyError` is raised:

```
try:
    leaderboard = automl.leaderboard()
except KeyError:
    leaderboard = "Error"
out += f"automl.leaderboard() : {leaderboard}\n\r"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a try/except block to do this.

```py
try:
    leaderboard = automl.leaderboard()
except KeyError:
    leaderboard = "Error"  # If there is an error, leaderboard will be set to "Error"
out = out + "automl.leaderboard() : " + leaderboard + "\n\r"
```